# Defining Google Tag Manager Data Layer variables

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I have a question about Google Tag Manager (GTM) and Data Layer:

Let's assume that the analytics team asks developers to push an event in `Data Layer` called "test" which has the following structure:

```
{
product_id : '1234',
category: 'toys' 
}
```

Let's assume I have a tag that needs to send those variables to a third party provider.

According to my understanding of the GTM workflow I have to create two separate data Layer variables, one for `product_id` and one for `category`.

This is quite a manual/long/error prone process for events with a lot of variables, and I also worry that there could be confusion if another variable is called ‘category’ from another event.

So my question is:

Can I define in GTM the 'parent' level variable called 'test' (the name of the event itself), and then create `test.product_id` and `test.category` variables?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proper data governance should dictate that your data layer keys are well defined so that you don't have redundancy and ambiguity. Also, use of the `event` key is vital if you absolutely need to reuse a particular name, like `category`, with a different event. In that example, your data layer variable can be used for whatever event, and the `event` itself will ensure that that key is getting the correct value into the correct event tag.

If you do need to use a nested data structure, make sure your data layer variable uses the proper dot notation as you've indicated (ie. `test.0.category`). Note that in much the same way, the enhanced ecommerce data layer parameters can accessed.

Comment: thanks for your answer. When you say `use of the event key is vital` you mean when creating variables in GTM?

Comment: When you push data to the dataLayer, it's a good practice to always push an `event` as well, eg. `dataLayer.push({'event': 'test', 'category': 'chicken'})`. That way you can be sure that when you want to fire your tag and use the correct `category` value, you can do so with the `test` event as your trigger.

Comment: Great, this is what I am doing, thanks. In regards to using nested data structure, would it be something like `dataLayer.push({'event': 'animal', 'animal':[{'name': 'chicken'}, {'habitat':'farm'}])` and then the variables will be defined as `animal.name` and `animal.farm`?

Comment: It would be more like `dataLayer.push({'event': 'animal', 'animal':[{'name': 'chicken', 'habitat':'farm'}])`, and then to access them as data layer variables in GTM, you would go `animal.0.name` and `animal.0.habitat`.

Comment: thanks, I think this is the best approach. This way I could define only a single variable `animal` in GTM and then access the single elements from the tag.